# Prove that fuction series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2(n-x)}{e^{(n-x)^2}}$ is convergent uniformly to function $G$ and find this $G$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that fuction series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2(n-x)}{e^{(n-x)^2}}$$ is  convergent uniformly to function $G$ and find this $G$.

I tried to calculate $$||f_n||=\sup _{x \in \mathbb R} |\frac{2(n-x)}{e^{(n-x)^2}}|$$ but I could not reach any meaningful conclusion because I know only that $|\frac{2(n-x)}{e^{(n-x)^2}}| \le 1$ but it is not helpfull for me because $\sum 1$ is divergent. Moreover I need formula for $ G $.
Have you get any hints how to do it?

Comment: you should find the supremum by looking for turning points. This would tell you about the uniform convergence of the series. As for actual summation of the series, if you differentiated $e^{-(n-x)^2}$ then you would get a nice $(n-x)$ at the front. So I'm suggesting you do term by term differentiation of the series with term $e^{-(n-x)^2}$. You can sum this series by seeing it is a geometric series with ratio $2x-1$.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst A geometric series with ratio $2x-1$ has the form $a(2x-1)^n$ for some $a$. How is $e^{-(n-x)^2}$ a geometric series with ratio $2x-1$?

Comment: sorry ratio $exp(2x-1)$. You can see it if you compute $exp(-(n+1-x)^2)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst - Sorry, but you are mistaken. The ratio between $e^{-(n+1-x)^2}$ and $e^{-(n-x)^2}$ is equal to $e^{2x-2n-1}$, and not to $e^{1-2x}$. Anyway, to your method, what is the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-(n-x)^2}$?

Comment: ok back to the drawing board on that one

Comment: I think the idea of going towards $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n-x)^2}$ seems right. If we are to work out the sum of this series, it seems like Parseval's theorem from Fourier Analysis might be a good idea. From there it is all about how to integrate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n-x)}e^{iny}$ times its conjugate (wrt y). You can do this sum geometrically. The resulting integral may be fairly tricky

Comment: I bet you can somehow get the result by interpreting $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n-x)^2}$ as sum of normal distributions (with $\mu = n, \sigma = 1/\sqrt 2$, and all scaled by a constant, identical factor)

Comment: I think that the integral form of the sum is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{2x}}{(cos^2(y)-e)^2+\sin^2y}dy$ using Parsevals

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $$f_n(x) = 2(n-x)e^{-(n-x)^2}$$

You can check the point-wise convergence by noticing that for any fixed $x$ the series $S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ is convergent; that follows from the fact that $$\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} = \frac{n+1-x}{n-x}e^{-(n+1-x)^2+(n-x)^2} = \frac{1 + \frac{1-x}{n}}{1-\frac{x}{n}}e^{-1-2n+2x} \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow\infty} 0 $$

Let us check the uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$.
Let us consider $$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$$ To prove the uniform convergence  on $\mathbb R$, we'd need to show that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |S(x)-S_n(x)| = 0$$ that is
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right| = 0$$
However it's not true. We have 
$$ \forall x \le k: f_k(x) \ge 0$$
so for a given $n$, if we take $x<n$ and $k>n$ we have
$$ \forall x \le n \,\forall k \ge n:f_k(x) \ge 0 $$
and from this it follows that
 $$ \forall x \le n : \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x) \ge 0$$
We have then $$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right| \ge \sup_{x \le n} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right| \ge \sup_{x \le n} f_{n+1}(x) \ge f_{n+1}(n-1) = 2e^{-1}$$
Therefore it's impossible that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right| = 0$$
so the series isn't uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$.

It is however almost uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$. It's easy to check that $f_n(x)$ is increasing for $x \le n+1$ That means that if $x\in[a,b]$ and $n\ge b+1$ then $$ f_n(x) \le f_n(b)$$
Since $\sum_n f_n(b)$ is convergent, it means that $\sum_n f_n(x)$ is convergent uniformly for $x\in[a,b]$, and that means that it is convergent almost uniformly for $x\in\mathbb R$.